# C++ — error with number of arguments

Tags: c++, loops

I can't seem to get my code to compile - this is the error I'm getting:

**6\problem11.cpp(21): error C2660: 'calcScore' : function does not take 0 arguments**

Any help or suggestions in solving this? This is a homework problem and I can't seem to figure out how to fix the error. We're not allowed to use arrays just yet.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getJudgeData(int);
void calcScore(float, float, float, float, float);
float findHighest(float, float, float, float, float);
float findLowest(float, float, float, float, float);

    int main()
    {
        getJudgeData(1);
        getJudgeData(2);
        getJudgeData(3);
        getJudgeData(4);
        getJudgeData(5);
        calcScore();

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    void getJudgeData(int jnumber)
{
    float score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;

    switch(jnumber)
    {
        case 1: cout << "\nEnter the score for judge " << jnumber << ". ";
                cin >> score1;
                break;
        case 2: cout << "\nEnter the score for judge " << jnumber << ". ";
                cin >> score2;
                break;
        case 3: cout << "\nEnter the score for judge " << jnumber << ". ";
                cin >> score3;
                break;
        case 4: cout << "\nEnter the score for judge " << jnumber << ". ";
                cin >> score4;
                break;
        case 5: cout << "\nEnter the score for judge " << jnumber << ". ";
                cin >> score5;
                break;
                calcScore(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    }
}

void calcScore(float one, float two, float three, float four, float five)
{
    float high, low, avg;

        high = findHighest(one, two, three, four, five);
        low = findLowest(one, two, three, four, five);

        avg = ((one + two + three + four + five) - (high+low))/3;

        cout << "Final score is: " << avg <<endl;
        return;
}

float findHighest(float high1, float high2, float high3, float high4, float high5) // find highest score 
{
    float high = 10;

        if (high1 > high)
        {
             high1 = high;
        }
        else if ( high2 > high)
        {
             high2 = high;
        }
        else if ( high3 > high)
        {
             high3 = high;
        }
        else if (high4 > high)
        {
             high4 = high;
        }
        else if ( high5 > high)
        {
             high5 =  high;
        }

        return  high;
}

float findLowest (float low1, float low2, float low3, float low4, float low5) // find lowest score
{
    float low = 1;

        if (low1 < low)
        {
            low1 = low;
        }
        else if (low2 < low)
        {
            low2 = low;
        }
        else if (low3 < low)
        {
            low3 = low;
        }
        else if (low4 < low)
        {
            low4 = low;
        }
        else if (low5 < low)
        {
            low5 = low;
        }

        return low;
}
```

Comment: The compiler has told you exactly what's wrong. You have a function `calcScore` which is supposed to take 5 floats, and you're calling it (in main) with no parameters.

Comment: Now redo your code to handle the largest of 10 values.  Then redo your code to pass an array into your 'find largest' and 'find smallest' functions.  Compare the two.  And then think about 200 values to be worked with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
calcScore();
```

You cant do this, since the function expects 4 parameters, as the compiler says.

Let me see if i understand what you want to do. Make these changes

```
float getJudgeData(int jnumber) //return the score
{
    float score; // only one score neeeded

    ...
    //calcScore(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
}
```

You can remove the last `calcScore` line since

a) it wont be reached anyway, it is after a break statement, within the switch.
b) You will ever have one score at this point.

```
int main()
{
    float score1, score2, score3, score4, score5;
    score1=getJudgeData(1);
    score2=getJudgeData(2);
    score3=getJudgeData(3);
    score4=getJudgeData(4);
    score5=getJudgeData(5);
    calcScore(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    ...
}
```

This might just do what you want - get each float, and call `calcScore` on them.

Comment: This is the homework problem : A particular talent competition has 5 judges, each of whom awards a score 
between 0 and 10 to each performer. Fractional scores, such as 8.3, are allowed. 
A performer’s final score is determined by dropping the highest and lowest score 
received, then average the three remaining scores. Write a program that uses this method to calculate a contestant’s score. It should include the following functions:

Comment: Void getJudgeData() should ask the user for a judge’s score, store it in a reference parameter variable, and validate it. This function should be called by main once for each of the five judges.
Void calcScore() should calculate and display the average of the three scores that remain after dropping the highest and lowest scores the performer received. This function should be called just once by main and should be passed the five scores. The last two functions should be called by calcScore(), which uses the returned information to determine which of the scores to drop.

Comment: @AnnaThpvng If your homework requires `void getJudgeData`, then you need to make some changes, else take a look at the changes I suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You have the line

```
calcScore();
```

But the function requires arguments (as declared and defined in the rest of the code).

Add the arguments!